Has the IDF killed more terrorist[s] on the "US watch list" in the last 4 weeks (i.e. Sep 2024) than the US has done in the last 20 years?
A comment from Sep 29 with some 800 upvotes on reddit claims that:

The IDF has killed more terrorist[s] on the US watch list in the last 4 weeks than the US has done in the last 20 years. It's really a masterclass.

Is this true? (The 'watch list' isn't terribly clear, perhaps it's talking about FBI's wanted list? Thanks to SIMEL for pointing out that the TSDB is sometimes informally called the "consolidated terrorist watchlist" in the US.)

Nasrallah himself wasn't on the US watch list, so I doubt this is true.

If we take a very broad definition of "watch list" (i.e. they are watching most of Hamas and Hezbollah) and a very broad and definition of "terrorist" (i.e. the same people again) then this could be true just because the IDF have killed a heck of a lot of people. Most of whom the US was keeping an eye on but not actually trying to kill.

@JackB That also begs the question if you would classify the watch list as a "kill" list and not just a list of people to keep an eye on.

@JoeW the person positing the comment does seem to be deliberately conflating the two concepts, yes.

I don't think the US want all people on the "US watch list" dead. They probably will not be sad about it but it is not the goal

@JackB there is a very real US terrorist watch list, it's called the "Terrorist Screening Database" and it holds more than 2 million individuals on it. It's not the "no fly list" which is also real and is a subset of the above. But, I'm not sure if it's accessible to the public and if it's available online.

@SIMEL: you're right that what it's probably referring to.

I think that a more accurate phrasing of the question would be "Israeli military" or "Israeli security forces".

@JoeW Given that at least the public characterization of the US list is that it is an investigative list, and that many people on the list are in the US and are not necessarily targeted for arrest much less killing, it seems quite problematic for anyone to characterize it as a "kill" list and imply that the US wants people on that list dead. The dynamic nature of the list with people regularly added and removed also does not suggest usefulness as a list of those the US would want dead, as death is rather permanent in most cases.

@SIMEL: probably in an answer, but the quote uses "IDF".

@BryanKrause That is my point, the watch list isn't a kill list so there is no point to comparing who did or didn't kill more people on the list.

@BryanKrause: true, but many on the list are "international terrorists" who never set foot in the US. So, the question/claim does have some  merit.

@Believeitornot... The rest on the list are "people who might be international terrorists and even though they've never set foot in the US we're hoping that we notice if they do in case they want to crash planes into buildings". Also includes people who have names similar to other people who might be international terrorists. It's a broad list meant to catch things for observation. Bit of a leap from there to "international terrorists we intend to kill".

@BryanKrause: the quote doesn't claim that kind of intent for the list. So arguing about this in comments seems rather pointless.

With "It's really a masterclass", it implies that people on the list dying is a good thing, and further by suggesting that it's impressive to have killed more on the list than the US suggests that the US has a goal to kill people on the list.

@BryanKrause It's a masterclass in collateral damage.
